# Javascript Double sorting algorithm

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I recently went through an interview where they asked me to come up with a sorting algorithm that really thew me off. Does anyone know the solution to this if it were to be done in javascript?

> Problem 1: Double Sort
>
> Please write a method which accepts an array of strings. Each element
>   can either be a number (`"165"`) or a word (`"dog"`). Your method should
>   sort and print the array such that (1) The words are printed in
>   alphabetical order and the numbers in numerical order, and (2) the
>   order of words and numbers within the array is the same.
>
> Examples (input => output):
>
> ```
> sort(['5', '4', 'dog', '1', 'cat'])
> => ['1', '4', 'cat', '5', 'dog']
>
> sort(['dog', 'cat'])
> => ['cat', 'dog']
>
> sort('5', '3')
> => ['3', '5']
> ```
>
> You can use standard library sort functions, and should assume that
>   all inputs will be valid. If you make any other assumptions, please
>   document those as well. You can use any programming language that
>   you'd like.
>
> Additionally, you may assume that you'll be given a utility method
>   that returns whether a given String is a valid number (e.g.
>   `isNumber()`, where `isNumber('dog')` returns `false`, and `isNumber('15')`
>   returns `true`).

Comment: Is not that hard, one way to solve it is to separate both elements in two separate arrays, sort them and then iterate through the unsorted array, if you find an integer, take an integer from the sorted integers array and if you find a String take it from the sorted Strings array

Comment: Be sure to make your algorithm as fast as possible order of operations O(n) <= n^2 if possible. They will probably look at that.

Comment: You could use a standard algorithm like Quicksort to sort the individual arrays and then merge these in the way higuaro proposed. That way the complexity will be `2*n^2+n`, thus `O(n) <= n^2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple approach - filter the input array into separate arrays of only strings and only numbers.  Then sort the homogeneously typed arrays per their natural ordering.  Then produce a final sorted array populated by the type of the indices in the original array.

For example:

```
function doubleSort(arr) {
  // Separate the values by type.
  var numbers=[], strings=[];
  arr.forEach(function(x) {
    if (isNumber(x)) {
      numbers.push(Number(x));
    } else {
      strings.push(x);
    }
  });
  // Sort strings and numbers separately.
  strings.sort();
  numbers.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });
  // Merge the sorted arrays by type from the input array.
  var sorted=[], nextNumber=0, nextString=0;
  arr.forEach(function(x) {
    if (isNumber(x)) {
      sorted.push(String(numbers[nextNumber++]));
    } else {
      sorted.push(strings[nextString++]);
    }
  });
  return sorted;
}

// XXX: lots of pitfalls but good enough for this exercise.
function isNumber(x) {
  return Number(x).toString() === x;
}
```

The Big-O performance is bound by the underlying sort algorithm, so likely `O(n log n)`.

Comment: Your numbers are not sorted numerically.

Comment: You've proven yourself worthy of that JS gold badge now ;-)

Comment: Heh, my recent playing with golang has made me forget to constantly check types ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Same idea and performance as the other answer. But written in something like coffeescript so it's easier to read

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a clumsy variation on quicksort that will sort either the numbers or the words in situ. (I modified a regular JavaScript quicksort posted by [Paul Lewis](https://gist.github.com/paullewis/1981455); not sure if all the kinks are completely ironed out...).

```
function isNumber(x,y) {
  return y ? Number(x).toString() !== x : Number(x).toString() === x;
}

function less(a,b,y){
  return y ? a < b : Number(a) < Number(b)
}

function swap(a, i, j) { var t = a[i]; a[i] = a[j]; a[j] = t; }

function partition(array, pivot, left, right, what) {
  var store = left,
      pivotValue = array[pivot];

  swap(array, pivot, right);

  for (var v = left; v < right; v++) {
    if (less(array[v],pivotValue,what) && isNumber(array[v],what)) {
      swap(array, v, store);
      store++;
    }
  }

  while(!isNumber(array[store],what))
    store++;

  swap(array, right, store);

  return store;
}

function doubleQSort(array, left, right, what) {
  while(!isNumber(array[right],what) && right > left)
    right--;
  while(!isNumber(array[left],what) && left < right)
    left++;

  var pivot = null;

  if (left < right) {
    pivot = (right + left) >> 1;

    while(!isNumber(array[pivot],what))
      pivot--;

    newPivot = partition(array, pivot, left, right, what);

    doubleQSort(array, left, newPivot - 1,what);
    doubleQSort(array, newPivot + 1, right,what);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
var things = ['dog', 'asdf','31','11','6','fat','cat', '4'];

doubleQSort(things,0,things.length - 1,'words');
doubleQSort(things,0,things.length - 1);
console.log(things);

[ "asdf", "cat", "4", "6", "11", "dog", "fat", "31" ]
```